# Error conversion varchar datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

I have this query:

```
update table 
set initTime = '2012-08-20 09:30:00.000' 
WHERE id='0124'
```

and it says:

> *conversion from varchar to datetime generated an out of range value.*

Can you help me out please?:(

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? I tried to update a datetime cell in AdventureWorksDW.DimTime with the same statement and it just worked fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be safe, you should use a language-independent date format for your date strings:

```
UPDATE dbo.table 
SET initTime = '2012-08-20T09:30:00.000' 
WHERE id = '0124'
```

See the difference? I added a `T` between the date and the time portion. This makes this a valid ISO-8601 date/time string, and this should work regardless of what SQL Server language and regional settings you have.

Without that `T` in the middle, it's not a proper ISO-8601 date/time string, and depending on your language/regional/dateformat settings in SQL Server it might be interpreted as *the 8th day of the 20th month of 2012* and of course, that 20th month sorta doesn't exist..... :-)

Answer (score 0):

or use YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS format. You can find out more about unambigious format is this post
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10898/understanding-datetime-column-part-ii.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to datetime and then feed it in the table.

```
update table 
set initTime = CONVERT(DateTime, '2012-08-20 09:30:00.000')
WHERE id='0124'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) before your statement. I think you have another DAY/MONTH order in your language settings:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
```

Comment: This is also not safe. Read my previous reply and refer the post